# onChange will not fire with delayed state changes and later added components ReactMeteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

A very basic and standard component which should call the change handler when the input changes.
It works in my pen: http://codepen.io/sdbondi/pen/MaGovq

It doesn't in my meteor app - in fact any handler (onClick, etc) doesn't work if rendered after the initial page load -  { (this.state.cond) ? `<Element onChange={..}/>` : ''} will also render but not fire the change.

Interestingly changes fire if I set the entries in the initial state, but with setTimeout they render but no onChange.

I've stepped through react to try and understand how events are bound (I actually got to  `addEventListener` eventually) but it'll take a while to understand what is happening enough to debug.

```
export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'VotePage',
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      entries: []
    };
  },

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // this will eventually be replaced by meteor data (ReactMeteor.createClass etc)
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({'entries': [{_id: '123', name: 'guyuy'}, {_id:234, name: 'sadfsd'}]});
    }, 1000);
  },

  render() {
    var voteEntries;

    if (this.state.entries && this.state.entries.length) {
      voteEntries = this.state.entries.map((entry) =>
        <input key={entry._id} name="entry" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={entry.name}  />
      );
    } else {
    voteEntries = 'loading...';
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <h2>Vote</h2>
          <div className="island_-small">
            {voteEntries}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

React: v0.13.0 (tried 0.13.3 too)

```
------------> versions excerpt 
react@0.1.13
react-meteor-data@0.1.9
react-runtime@0.13.3_7
react-runtime-dev@0.13.3_7
react-runtime-prod@0.13.3_6
reactive-dict@1.1.3
reactive-var@1.0.6
reactjs:react@0.2.4
kadira:flow-router@2.7.0
kadira:react-layout@1.4.1


----------> packages full file
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.

dburles:collection-helpers
aldeed:collection2
accounts-base
accounts-password
alanning:roles
# twbs:bootstrap
# fortawesome:fontawesome
wylio:mandrill
# kadira:blaze-layout
# sach:flow-db-admin
check


stevezhu:lodash
accounts-facebook
service-configuration
kadira:flow-router
universe:modules-npm
ecmascript
fixate:app-deps
universe:modules
yasaricli:slugify
maxharris9:classnames
reactjs:react
kadira:react-layout
jquery
react-meteor-data
meteorhacks:subs-manager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was something in `reactjs:react`. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor/issues/105

I made this mixin based on froatsnooks response on github:

```js
    export const MeteorReactSubscriber = {
      componentWillMount() {
        this._subsMap = {};
        this.subscriptions();
        this._startMeteorTracker();
      },
    
      _startMeteorTracker() {
        this._subsHandle = Tracker.autorun(() => {
          this.subscriptionReady && this.subscriptionReady();
          if (this.meteorSubsReady()) {
            this.meteorDataReady && this.meteorDataReady();
          }
        });
      },
    
      meteorSubsReady() {
        return _.all(this._subsMap, (s, _) => s.ready());
      },
    
      meteorSubscribe(name, selector=undefined) {
        this._subsMap[name] = Meteor.subscribe(name, selector);
      },
    
      componentWillUnmount() {        
        this._subsHandle.stop();
        this._subsMap = null;
      }
    };
```

### Usage

```js
    var SweetComponent = React.createClass({
      mixins: [MeteorReactSubscriber],
      subscriptions() {  
        this.meteorSubscribe('entries');
      },
    meteorDataReady() { 
      var currentEntry = Entry.findOne(this.props.entryId);
      this.setState({entry});
    },
    render() { ... }  
    });
```